# styling text regions with class selector from global QSS

Tags: qt, css-selectors, qtstylesheets

How can I style a span that is part of a widget text (e.g.
a QLabel) via global style sheet?

E.g. in below example, both *foo* and *bar* should be red.

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

class
some_label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    some_label(QString text = "") : QLabel(NULL) {
        setText(text);
        show();
    };
};
#include "main.moc"

static const char *css =
        "some_label { color : blue; background : black; }"
        "span.some_class { color : red; }";

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyleSheet(css);
    some_label label("before "
                     "<span style=\"color:red;\">foo</span> " /* works */
                     "<span class=\"some_class\">bar</span> " /* fails */
                     "after");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Qmake (Qt 5.1.1) project file:

```
QT      += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

[image: Unsatisfactory result]

I would really appreciate a solution that avoids hardcoding the style as I did
with the *foo* span.
The goal is for the application look to be determined entirely by a
user-supplied style sheet (represented by `css` in the example).
At the moment I use a workaround involving separate labels for each element
that is colored and it is a nightmare to maintain.

I have consulted a few online sources as well as Blanchette/Summerfield chapter
19 but those are primarily concerned with styling whole widgets.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to change styling after the `QLabel` loads, you could devise a system where you text-replace the colors you want for each word from a centralized style file:

```
// These values come from a central, user-supplied style sheet, etc.
QString primary = "red";
QString secondary = "green";

some_label label("before "
                 "<font color=\"" + secondary + "\">foo</font> "
                 "<font color=\"" + primary   + "\">bar</font> "
                 "after");
```

This system is a little hard to read but it could be an improvement over using many `QLabel`s.

(As you may have noticed, [Qt doesn't support CSS selection of classes within QLabels](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25641).)